# How to change v-dialog css styling dynamically

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

The goal is to be able to resize a `v-dialog` on click of a button.
Usually I can apply dynamic css classes to vuetify components via `:class` prop.
However, `v-dialog` requires use of the `content-class` in order to apply css class to it.

How can I accomplish something like code below on a v-dialog:

```
  <v-dialog
    persistent
    scrollable
    v-model="dialog"
    :class="{ 'my-css-class-name': myBooleanFlag }"
    style="position: relative;"
  >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `:content-class="myBooleanFlag ? 'my-css-class-name' : ''"` :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      myBooleanFlag: true,
      dialog: true
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.my-css-class-name {
  background: violet;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div data-app id="app">
  <v-dialog
    persistent
    scrollable
    v-model="dialog"
    :content-class="myBooleanFlag ? 'my-css-class-name' : ''"
    style="position: relative;"
  >
  <button @click="myBooleanFlag = !myBooleanFlag">click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Nikola, 
:content-class="myBooleanFlag ? 'my-css-class-name' : ''" --- works even with vuetify 1.5.XX
Interesting that syntax used everywhere in project did not work for v-dialog when I tried this:
:content-class="'my-css-class-name' : myBooleanFlag"

Comment: content-type is of type string per docs, but why is in this scenario "'my-css-class-name' : myBooleanFlag" -- 'my-css-class-name'  is not considered a string? Does it not read as "Only apply 'my-css-class-name' if myBooleanFlag is true?" @Nikola

Comment: Sure it is, but `myBooleanFlag` is boolean and as whole ... and in `:content-class="myBooleanFlag ? 'my-css-class-name' : ''"` you get string in any condition